# Play framework: update web page when a value is selected from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, playframework

I am using play framework for the first time.

I want to update the web page when a value is selected from drop down with out refreshing the web page.

Consider the following example:

```
<select>
  <option value= "Apple"> Apple </option>
  <option value = "Banana"> Banana </option>
</select>
```

When a value is selected from drop down it should be posted to server. Then server should return some information based on the value it got. Now we should display the content corresponding to the value selected from drop down with out page refresh.

I didn't find a way to implement this using play framework. Conventionally we can do this by hiding a div initially and when a value is selected from drop down we can add content (fetched from back end) to the div and show it. I didn't understand how to implement the server side part. In play framework, controller generally returns Result type. How to return a Json value on a request in play framework ?

Can anyone please suggest other ideas ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using jQuery (see [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    $('#select').change(function() {
        $('#result').load('/foo/bar?fruit=' + $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: To address the JSON/server-side part of the question have a look at [ScalaJsonHttp](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonHttp) (or [JavaJsonActions](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonActions)).

Comment: You might also like to use Play's JavaScript routing to improve the ugly string concatenation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting